# Difference in a file on two different computers

Tags: file, networking, filesystems, communication

There two computers having same number of many files. How do we find out if there is a slight change in any one of the file in One computer. The Network communication is very slow between these computers

Answer (score 2):

You can use md5sum utility. For windows please check [this] (https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/889768/how-to-compute-the-md5-or-sha-1-cryptographic-hash-values-for-a-file) and for linux use `md5sum filename` and then compare the hash values.

Answer (score 0):

You could hash the files and compare the hashes via the network.

A good hashfunction is designed that if there is only a little difference in the input of the function, then the output will be totally different. Furthermore most hashfunctions have a output-length of 160-512 bits nowadays. Meaning although you might want to compare two files which are several gigabyte big you would only need to send a small string of 512 bits over the network to see if the hashes match.

If you have millions of files maybe this would be already to much. A solution would look like this:

1. Hash each file on each computer
2. Then concatenate the hashes and hash the concatenated string again
3. Now compare this output if it differs you know, that there is a difference in those files.
4. To find which file differs (or even where exactly in the file) you can use binary search:
5. Split the millions of files into two parts, now go to step 1-3 (if you have enough space you could save the hash of each file to speed up).
6. Now for each of the two hashes which differ go to step 4-6 recursively.
7. If you located the files that differ you could again split up the file by the number of lines and work like in 4-6.
8. At some point the number of lines will be such small that the hash maybe would be longer than the actual content of the lines. Now it is of course more efficient to compare the actual content in the naive way.

Assuming you would have only one file which differs this would only need logarithmic many hashes to be sent over the network and therefore minimize the network traffic.

Comment: Thanks ... Can you please elaborate a little I have been asked this question in an interview for position related to Web Security (Clearly I am not fit for it). Let me rephrase the question : 
The are millions of files in two systems and the network is slow, How we can check if the there is one character is wrong in any one  file

Comment: @VivekKumar see my edit

Answer (score 0):

One idea would be to generate a hash for each file. Hashes convert an arbitrary length file to a fixed size. You could further hash the hashes together, then upload it and compare. Hashing is something used extensively to ensure downloads are not corrupt.

Comment: Thanks ... Can you please elaborate a little I have been asked this question in an interview for position related to Web Security (Clearly I am not fit for it). Let me rephrase the question : The are millions of files in two systems and the network is slow, How we can check if the there is one character is wrong in any one file

Comment: Do you want to find the specific character or just find the file with the misaligned character?